# Can OpenOffice Calc read web services to populate fields?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

I have created a web service that provides me with sales data from our corporate ERP system.  We are going to use this to drive some "dashboards" showing this data graphically.

For testing/ evaluation I would like to use a web service like a custom function to populate individual fields in a spreadsheet. I can't see how to d this easily in MS Excel (2007) but wonders if OpenOffice Calc has a capability.

My hope/expectation is that I type in a call the web service in each cell and e web service reply (a sales number relating to the web service call is returned and displayed in the cell.

My web service is called something like this:
`http://server:8080/SalesHistory?Year=2011&Month=10&Region=Europe&Channel=Web`

As you can guess, this will return the value of sales for October'11 for the region/sales channel stated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you will have to do a little bit of programming (which can be done in e.g. Python, C++ or Java, or maybe even OOo/LibO Basic) to create your own Calc function.  If you like to use Python, search the web for "python uno bridge" (or replace "python" with your favourite language).

(BTW: something similar is also possible in MS Excel really...)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the new `WEBSERVICE` and `FILTERXML` functions in LibreOffice 4.2: http://lodahl.blogspot.de/2013/12/libreoffice-now-has-built-in-xml-parser.html

See also https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/WEBSERVICE

In 5.2.2, support was improved to handle array/matrix contexts. See https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88257

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can create a "Job" with OpenRefine that can process data through a web service and drop it into the file format of your choice. Not sure what already exists for OpenDocument formats. Watch the videos here for more info:

http://openrefine.org/